# SELECT TOP query in access results not shown

Tags: sql, ms-access, report

With access 2016, I have a query that fails when I try to add TOP and ORDER BY like:

```
SELECT TOP 16 table_name.a, table_name.b, Left([table_name.c],2) AS c1, Mid([table_name.d],2) AS d1, table_name.e
FROM table_name
WHERE (((table_name.e)<3001))
ORDER BY table_name.a, table_name.b, Left([table_name.c],2), Mid([table_name.d],2), table_name.e
```

I can see results from this query when I look at

- datasheet view of the query in Query Builder
- layout view of the form that contains the query
- double click the form (from the left-hand nav)

However, results are NOT shown when the full blown report is run (the report contains a subform which runs this query). Results show in the report without the TOP and ORDER BY.

[image: Success case]

[image: Failure case]

Comment: This is unclear. Is subform bound to a full query or this query which you label *subquery*?  If the former, please show full query. Are we talking forms or reports? Your title says one but body discusses report. You may need to better outline **entire** process going on here.

Comment: Thanks for your response Parfait; edits made.

Comment: Still unclear. I still see *the form* in two bullet points. Does report really contain a subform or a subreport? What does *full blown report* mean --isn't that double clicking from Nav Pane? Print Preview? Report View? Maybe add screenshots to show results that appear and do not.

Comment: Screenshots added."New State APD with Forms" report contains the "FORM1C_ALLSOURCES_SUB" report.

Comment: It may be due to relationship of subreport and main report. When you add `TOP` and `ORDER BY` none of those subreport records correspond to main report and hence a blank output. Carefully check the join IDs between both recordsources.

Comment: I found the Record Source property for the subreport (FORM1C_ALLSOURCES_SUB) and the report (New State APD with Forms). Where can I find the join IDs between the two? Thank you.

Comment: In the design view of the report. Click the subreport object and under Property Sheet \ Data (tab), see the *link master fields* and *link child fields*.